# Coffeescript / Node.js: How to remove duplicate objects from an array of objects?

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, coffeescript

How can I turn this array of objects (which has some duplicate objects):

```
items =
  [
    { TYPEID: 150927,  NAME: 'Staples',    COLOR: 'Silver' },
    { TYPEID: 1246007, NAME: 'Pencils',    COLOR: 'Yellow' },
    { TYPEID: 1246007, NAME: 'Pencils',    COLOR: 'Blue'   },
    { TYPEID: 150927,  NAME: 'Staples',    COLOR: 'Black'  },
    { TYPEID: 1248350, NAME: 'Staples',    COLOR: 'Black'  },
    { TYPEID: 1246007, NAME: 'Pencils',    COLOR: 'Blue'   },
    { TYPEID: 150927,  NAME: 'Staples',    COLOR: 'Silver' },
    { TYPEID: 150927,  NAME: 'Fasteners',  COLOR: 'Silver' }
  ]
```

Into this:

```
items =
  [
    { TYPEID: 150927,  NAME: 'Staples',    COLOR: 'Silver' },
    { TYPEID: 1246007, NAME: 'Pencils',    COLOR: 'Yellow' },
    { TYPEID: 1246007, NAME: 'Pencils',    COLOR: 'Blue'   },
    { TYPEID: 150927,  NAME: 'Staples',    COLOR: 'Black'  },
    { TYPEID: 1248350, NAME: 'Staples',    COLOR: 'Black'  },
    { TYPEID: 150927,  NAME: 'Fasteners',  COLOR: 'Silver' }
  ]
```

...by filtering out the two duplicate objects (the silver staples and the blue pencils)?

It seems like there should be an easy way to do this, but I've yet to find a simple solution.

I've seen some javascript / jquery code which does this, but I'm not the best at converting those into coffeescript.

UPDATE:

There will often be different objects with the very similar properties.

In the actual application, each object has a potential of 25 properties.

I only want to remove objects if each of those properties are equal.

**UPDATE 2**

This is the code that ended up working for me - (thanks to **rjz**)

```
unique = (objAry, callback) ->
  results = []

  valMatch = (seen, obj) ->
    for other in seen
      match = true
      for key, val of obj
        match = false unless other[key] == val
      return true if match
    false

  objAry.forEach (item) ->
    unless valMatch(results, item)
      results.push(item)
  callback null, results
```

And this is how I'll call it:

```
unique items, (err, items) ->
  console.log items
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending how deeply you want to check equality, you could probably just assume uniqueness of the `USERID` field and do something like this:

```
ids = []    # Contains list of "seen" IDs
result = [] # Contains list of unique users

users.forEach (u) -> 
  if result.indexOf(u.USERID) == -1
    result.push(u)
    ids.push(u.USERID)
```

If you need to do deeper matching and don't have a primary key available (might be a sign of bigger issues), you could create a more sophisticated test for equality:

```
valMatch = (seen, obj) ->
  for other in seen
    match = true
    for key, val of obj
      match = false unless other[key] == val
    return true if match
  false

result = []
seen = []

data.forEach (datum) -> 
  unless valMatch(result, datum)
    result.push(datum)
    seen.push(datum)
```

Comment: That would work, but there will often be different objects with the same USERID.  In the actual application, each object has a potential of 25 properties.  I only want to remove objects if those properties are completely identical (like the example).

Comment: Well, the strategy will be the same--the equality check just gets a little more complicated. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Got it. Best to just smile and nod, then :^)

Answer (score 0):

I would use underscore.js and try something like this

```
result = item[0] for item in _.groupBy(users, (user) => user.USERID)
```

Its not tested thou ;-) obviously this assumes that we only check for the USERID

if you can't only check for the USERID you could of course transform all objects into json-strings and then compare the json strings

```
result = item[0] for item in _.groupBy(users, (user) => user.toJSON())
```

obviously this is a dirty hack that will rely on the fact that all browsers and engines serialize objects and their slots in the order of creation/assignment.

So in any way rjz's solution is certainly the better one but this will most likely work as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't filter objects on the ID alone.  I've changed the objects from "Users" to "Items" to help make the issue clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old Question - but oldies are ...

lets join the objects within the array:
(get all values into an array and join it to a string)

```
join_object=(o)->
    ["#{attr}:#{value}" for attr, value of o].join()
```

this generates an output like that for each obj.

```
    TYPEID:150927,NAME:Staples,COLOR:Silver
```

and lets make a deep unique modifying the Coffee way of 'uniquen' an Array:

```
Array::unique_deep = ->
    output = {}
    output[join_object(@[key])] = @[key] for key in [0...@length]
    value for key, value of output
```

Short and save.

the result:

```
Array::unique_deep = ->
    join_object=(o)->
        ["#{attr}:#{value}" for attr, value of o].join()
    output = {}
    output[join_object @[key]] = @[key] for key in [0...@length]
    value for foo_key, value of output
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Array::uniq = ->
    unique=(v, k, self) ->
        self.indexOf(v)==k
    @.filter(unique)

# console.log([1,2,3,3,4,4,5].uniq())
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.